# Samhain performance and trouble shooting on Centos 6

Tags: security, centos

I am new user to Samhain so don't know much about it except the fact why its used. Now I am finding my samhain-2.8.5 on centos-6 is consuming too much of CPU. Its almost eating up 2 cores and I cant find the reason. I tried little bit googling but it does not seems to help me when it comes to troubleshoot this problem.

In samhain logs all I could find is

```
3277BD028C279FC54B43E656BB3EA8E17A50136FF56B2085
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:58:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
DB1F18F7BF0118EA2A0A2E3CE0F227306AA2240F7D415D86
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:59:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
CB231517356010B7491CB428D7A83FCEE60A1FE4D829286A
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:00:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
C2911B37C38C028B707E7B0ECA96B22495A19853A53D9D10
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:01:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
7C33C05ACD870F9C866BAF73F33A9AF6A53937ADA3093425
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:02:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
5E45F7AF951EF082D4D1E0F4C8122543FBE247A9C231D75F
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:03:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
9A534980763124616000F1B9206A15825019F31E5E5746E3
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:04:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
E01DFCE3D446CE7471480A0620A65371043E283E9EC2EF6C
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:05:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
66B3BDCE9B0003BBC852DFD26D65338E1B1AEF657BECE076
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:06:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
4B8B1419285EFA450F38B6C11FF9DE33BD9294F8B9DF4ECC
MARK   :  [2012-11-01T15:07:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
093D24204088E3132B53D0158F4213DB9752282D21491F3B
```

Appreciate any input in this regard. The server is in production.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. It could be the  signing issue that lead to such a performance hit. Not sure weather newer versions have some means to inform end users.